# How do I write a terraform module representing an EC2 instance with an EBS volume and elastic IP address attached?

Tags: javascript, python, php, go

In this directory, you will find a VPC and security group set up to allow SSH. You will need to copy your public key into this directory and rename it to public_key. In instance.tf you will find a module block called challenge, note the variables and outputs and implement the module code in the instance subdirectory.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?  Sounds like it and I am not sure the site is set up to do your homework.  What have **you** done so far?  Show your code and then error/question arising from said code.